# Extension Method in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, extension-methods

What namespace do I need to get my extension to work

Here is my Extension Method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace MyUtilities
{
    public static class DataReaderExtensions
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable(IDataReader reader)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(reader);
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use it in like this

```
Session["Master"] = cust.GetCustomerOrderSummary((string)Session["CustomerNumber"]).ToDataTable();
```

it doesn't work. This is .net 2.0

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't. C# 2.0 doesn't have extension methods at all. You can use extension methods from C# 3.0 in Visual Studio 2008 *targeting* .NET 2.0 as described in my ["C#/.NET versions" article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) but you can't persuade a C# 2.0 compiler to act as if it understands what extension methods are.

Answer (score 25):

The tags say .NET 2.0; If you are using C# 3.0 (i.e. VS 2008) and targetting .NET 2.0, you can do this by declaring the ExtensionAttribute - or (easier) just reference [LINQBridge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqBridge/).

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class |
        AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

With this in place, extension methods will work in .NET 2.0 with C# 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods will not work in C# 2 because they rely on the C# 3 compiler.  The C# 3 compiler knows how to do the translation from this:

```
foo.Bar()
```

to this:

```
ExtensionClass.Bar(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

As JS said, C# 2.0 doesn't have extension methods.

Also that extension method would be defined as:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IDataReader reader)
```

Try calling it like:

```
DataReaderExtensions.ToDataTable(
   cust.GetCustomerOrderSummary((string)Session["CustomerNumber"])
   )
```