# How to inject method to auto property in .Net Framework

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-2.0

I have some class Foo with many properties:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }

    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

In other class I have some method, e.g.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    //...
}
```

How to inject this method to every setter of properties in the class Foo?
I use .Net Framework 2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically insert a method call on each property of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569223/programmatically-insert-a-method-call-on-each-property-of-a-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found easy way to do this. I use [EasyProp](http://code.google.com/p/easyprop/), which uses Castle [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html):

My class:

```
[AfterPropertySetFilter(typeof(NotifyPropertyChanged))]
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public virtual int Property1 { get; set; }

    public virtual int Property2 { get; set; }

    public virtual int Property3 { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Example of use:

```
    EasyPropBuilder epb=new EasyPropBuilder();
    Foo foo = epb.Build<Foo>();
    foo.Property1 = 1;
    foo.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    foo.Property1 = 2;
```

Also you need to add such method:

```
public static void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property Changed: " + propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what @rally25rs suggested?

Comment: Almost. I'm not quite figured out how to work with DynamicProxy, but EasyProp helped me.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a way to do that at runtime with reflection. What you would probably want to do is use an AOP (aspect-oriented) approach, but that too isn't really supported by the .NET framework.  You could use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/aop.net) to do it, if you don't mind using a compiler extension, or look into using [Unity2 to do AOP](http://www.google.com/search?q=aop+unity+2).

Edit:
You could also consider [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html).
Or, if you have a firm grasp of DynamicMethods and IL code, you could make your own proxy generator class.

However, I think in most cases, you will have to code the rest of your application appropriately to handle the proxies. In other words, instead of doing:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.Property1 = 123;
```

You would have to do something like:

```
Foo f = Generator.GetProxy<Foo>(); // this code is fake. just indicates that you need to get an instance of Foo from a proxy generator, be it DynamicProxy or Unity or whatever.
f.Property1 = 123;
```

Comment: Postsharp is probably the best solution here unless you want to make structural changes to your application to support this requirement.

Comment: @tom - I tend to agree, PostSharp will require the smallest change to already-existing code, since it has the advantage of doing the proxy generation and injection at build-time instead of at run-time. Some people don't like to use a compiler extension though, so I threw in the other options. Side-note; MS should just buy the rights to PostSharp and build it into the standard compiler! :)

Comment: With PostSharp was a problem. It doesn't want to interact with System.Data.SQLite: said that assembly is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension of the `int` class here. Or whatever data type your getter/setter properties are.

For example

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }    
    public int Property2 { get; set; }    
    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

The extension method would look like this

```
public static class IntExtension
{
    public static void SomeMethod(this int property)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

See the following article to use it with .NET 2.0. Requires that you use a VisualStudio that supports C# 3.0 but it will still work with the output framework as C# 2.0

[Extension Method in C# 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707145/extension-method-in-c-2-0)